# How to convert existing XML to Nokogiri's Builder syntax?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'd like to create a XML file with Nokogiri from scratch. I would like to use Builder syntax e.g.:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
xml.root {
xml.products {
  xml.widget {
    xml.id_ "10"
    xml.name "Awesome widget"
  }
 }
}
end
puts builder.to_xml
```

I already have a file which I want to use as a template, but I don't want to convert manually 200+ lines of XML code to Builders's syntax. Is there a convenient way to convert existing XML code to Builder's syntax?

Comment: I believe you should write a simple `xslt` for that with `<xsl:output method="text"/>` producing nokogiri´s builder.